# Is it possible to delete all values of an postgreSQL array in one query without using too many logical operators?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Hello everyone I was wondering if there is a way to delete all values within an array without making the query too long using logical operators.

**This is what I got so far. I can only delete 1 value at a time**

```
update invitationtable 
set inviteeaccepted = array_remove(inviteeaccepted, '1') 
where reservationid='99489'
```

**Here is my table**

[image: Here is my table]

my postgress version: "PostgreSQL 12.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

Comment: `update invitationtable set inviteeaccepted = '{}'::text[] where reservationid = 99489;`

Comment: Thanks! this worked but I cannot mark your comment as best for some reason.

Comment: That's quite all right that you cannot accept it.  I did not answer your original question of how to remove all items at the same time.  I cheated by replacing the entire array :-)  I am glad this works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the value to an empty array without specifying the type (or really, relying on implicit type conversion in Postgres):

```
update invitationtable 
    set inviteeaccepted = '{}'
    where reservationid = 99489;
```

I removed the single quotes from `99489` because presumably `reservationid` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the solution in the context of a script (like i was):
in my example i was executing a loop and wanted to re-use the array.
after the declare e.g. metas integer[];

you just null the variable each time i start the loop:
metas := null;

```
do $$
declare
total_loops integer; --set a value either here or before the loop
ag_s integer[];
metas integer[];
begin
for k in 1..total_loops loop
    Metas:=null;
    --do some other stuff
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

code here